# What is a "Letter of impact"?

Tags: applications

I recently applied to for a position. I just heard back from their Staffing Project Manager and she's asking for a "Letter of Impact".

> If you are still interested, please forward to me
> ...
>
> - A letter of impact. The letter of impact should specifically state how your experience/qualifications can/will make an immediate impact on our company’s continued and substantial growth.

Does anyone have an idea of what they're looking for here. I've never heard the term and google is failing me at the moment.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but doesn't the quote that you provide tell exactly what they are looking for? A letter that ties your experience and qualifications (probably those mentioned in the job description) to the company's execution and growth?

Comment: It *sounds* like they basically want a cover letter.  Googling "letter of impact" is rather depressing.

Comment: Sounds like you've run into your first case of managerial jargon. Only thing that can be done for that is to read between the lines and find out what she's really looking for (fortunately, it looks like the bullet point you included describes it pretty well).

Comment: BTW, that bullet point really just summarizes what you should be thinking about anyway.  They aren't going to hire you for just your skills (which many applicants will have), they are hiring you to make an impact with those skills.

Comment: I'm happy to improve the question of anyone can explain the downvote...

Comment: I would treat a request like this as a red flag. Unless you have a specialized skill set or some unique insight into this company's potential weaknesses that you could actually help with, you'll just be writing trite fluff to stroke the hiring manager's ego.

Comment: I thought it seemed a bit strange too @Eric. Any particular reason you call it a red flag though? What do you think this could be indicative of?

Comment: @ThatGuy The request is simply too demanding. How can you say without detailed knowledge of the possibilities / problems in the company how you can **immediately** assist with **substantial** growth.  If you did have a get rich quick scheme like that, why wouldn't you start your own company or work for yourself?  Also, if you were interesting enough to follow up on, why not a phone screen where she could get a direct feeling for what you could add?

Comment: @Eric I thin you're reading too much into the specific terms.  These sound more like managerial buzzwords than direct imperatives.  It sounds like they're just trying to encourage prospective employees to emphasize how they can contribute to their business. It does not sound like they are asking for a "get-rich-quick scheme" or anything of the sort.

Comment: @Zibbobz see my above comment about writing trite fluff.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like they've described exactly what they're looking for in their letter to you - a specific type of 'cover letter' sort of thing that advertises the impact you will have on their business.

It's a rather unusual way to ask for a cover letter, but it also gives you an idea of what kind of cover letter they're looking for - one that cites experience relevant to the job, and describes how your experience and abilities are useful to them as a business.

If that explains what they're looking for to you, then write that cover letter highlighting your personal skills and the way they relate to the job you've applied for, then send it to her, attached to an email that explains that what is attached is your 'letter of impact'.

---

If you need more clarity than that, you could always call the project manager and ask them.  Say something like:

> Hello, I'm (your name), I recently got a letter from you after applying for a job, asking for a Letter of Impact.  This is the first time I've heard of a Letter of Impact, could you please explain what you're looking for?

Try to be polite - this is something the manager has probably asked for from other people, and they might not have thought about the odd phrasing until now.  Also try to have another question or two to ask, so that it doesn't seem like you called for something trivial - it might be more common in her line of work than either you or I are aware of, so don't be offended if she acts like it should be obvious. Just accept the explanation she gives and write the best letter you can.